# Use multiple style tags in the A tag

Tags: html, styles

Just so you know, I'm still learning HTML, and I'm not very knowledgeable.

So I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple styles to one of my buttons on my navbar

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
  <a href="#interests">Interests</a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
```

On the bottom line I want to include: (You will need to use the style sheet below for the HTML to format correctly its just above the last sentence.)

```
style="background-color: #04AA6D"
```

Into the the code so that the background is turned green

I have this working on the other buttons that aren't floating right

here's my main pages one, the button named "home" is green on the back and that's how I want the About pages one to be.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a style="background-color: #04AA6D" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#skilss">Skills</a>
  <a href="#interests">Interests</a>
  <a style="float:right" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
```

I'm using this style sheet (Needed for the page to format correctly.)

```
    <style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
        }
        li {
          float: left;
        }
        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
</style>
```

I hope you understand what I mean, I'm horrible at explaining things . Any Questions you need me to answer so that you can help please let me know

I tried connecting the two together like this

```
<a style="float:right" style="background-color: #04AA6D" href="#contact">Interests</a>
```

But that didn't work

Comment: make individual `class` for `<a>` tag and then you can easily style them. If something is missed then let me know.

Comment: So something along the lines of <a style="float:right"><a style="background-color: #04AA6D" href="#contact">Interests</a>

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      
      #navbar {
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        transition: top 0.3s;
      }

.style1{
  float:right !important;
}

.style2{
  background: #04AA6D;
}
      
      #navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
      }
      
      #navbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }
              li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color: #111;
              }
              li {
                float: left;
              }
              li a {
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
              }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a style="background-color: #04AA6D" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#skilss">Skills</a>
  <a href="#interests">Interests</a>
  <a class="style1 style2" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
```

You can implement the following approach:

Create classes for different CSS:

```
.style1{
  float:right !important;
//i used '!important' because you are overriding other class
}

.style2{
  background-color: #04AA6D
}

.style3{
  //your 3rd extra css here
}
```

Then you can implement multiple css in following way:

```
<a class="style1 style2 style3">Example</a>
```